# Finding $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{mnp(m+n+p+1)}. $

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

> Find 
>   $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{mnp(m+n+p+1)}. $$

Use $$ \frac{1}{m+n+p+1}=\int_{0}^{1}{{{t}^{m+n+p}}\,dt} $$ so the sum equals $ -\int_0^1\ln^3(1-t)\,dt. $

But I don't understand the way that sum is that integral (or how the integral is distributed or something like this).

Help $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2):

For suitable $x$, we have $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty x^m$. Integrating it follows that $$\displaystyle -\ln(1-x) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^m}{m}$$

Hence

$$-\ln^3(1-x) = \left( - \ln(1-x) \right)^3 = \left( \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^m}{m} \right)\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} \right)\left( \sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{x^p}{p} \right)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks Simon S !